# pass dynamic summary queries to an MVC view from an EF model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Translate code in Laravel to asp.net mvc. I am passing a subset of the model and summarizing the fields by year.  My EF model has 50+ fields.

This is my Laravel route:

```
Route::get('/metrics', 'MetricsController@index');
```

My Laravel Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MetricsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
         $metrics = DB::select('select year(date_id) as Year, Sum(Revenue) from metrics Group By year(date_id)');

        return ($metrics);
    }
}
```

I would like to display the model data in a @foreach loop in the view?  The dump in the Laravel view displays the data in the following way.

```
[{"Year":2009,"Sum(Revenue)":"61302670.65"},
 {"Year":2011,"Sum(Revenue)":"68397989.00"},
 {"Year":2012,"Sum(Revenue)":"69245803.00"},   
 {"Year":2013,"Sum(Revenue)":"67184051.00"},
{"Year":2014,"Sum(Revenue)":"33445434.00"}]
```

Comment: Do you already have some C#/MVC code that you started? If so, could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will keep it simple, sticking to the fact that you need to show the data in the View. For that, I will assume that you already have your DbContext, Models and data loading parts ready.

**Model**

I will create a sample model just for the sake of example. But it could, obviously, be more advanced.

```
public class Result
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public decimal SumRevenue { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method (in the Controller)**

The most important here is the fact that you are loading a "List of" model as result of your query. As you are using EF, you could load it directly from your DbContext or probably use a repository pattern. Since we don't know, I am just making a simple method call so just imagine the DB logic is in there :)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Here is where you load your data. I am using this line just as example.
    List<Result> resultList = RandomLibrary.LoadData();

    return View(resultList)
}
```

**View**

Remember to prepare your View to receive the List you got in the Action Method.

```
@model List<Result>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Year: </strong>@item.Year
        <br />
        <strong>Sum of revenue: </strong>@item.SumRevenue
    </p>
}
```

This is an oversimplification of the process. You can see it in more details in the [official documentation](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Or just let us know if you will need a more detailed explanation as your case might be a bit different.

Comment: Thanks, I have discovered Micro ORM's which should do it however your answer is also a viable solution!